# How to remove menu class if submenu is empty

Tags: c#, jquery

I have binding to **`<UL>`** using repeater control.

```
<ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMenu_OnItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#li<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>" class="collapsed active"><a id="A1">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />
        <%#Eval("Name")%>
        <span class="arrow"></span></a>
      </li>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="li<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChildMenu" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
              <a id="A2" href='<%#Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></a>
            </li>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

If there are no sub-menu item(s), arrow icon should be hidden or should not be rendered:

```
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

Comment: can you paste the parsed html?

Comment: try to use `.children()` with `.length` maybe you can work something out of it

Comment: I've not worked in `c#` before, but as per your code above, you can try printing `<span>` tag conditionally, e.g. `<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex > 0 ? Eval('<span class="arrow"></span>') : '' %>`